# Calculating Autocorrelation (ACF) : coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, float found

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, math, time-series, correlation

I want to use Autocorrelation plots from pandas.plotting in order to check randomness in time series. My dataframe looks like this :

```
    DATE                reqUser     sum_event_count
0   2017-10-08 21:00:00 bddfdpadm   92542.0
1   2017-10-11 06:00:00 bscdpadm    1913.0
2   2017-10-11 11:00:00 ambari-qa   240.0
3   2017-10-11 14:00:00 A454275     6834.0
4   2017-10-13 04:00:00 cdndpadm    20737.0
```

I tried this :

```
from pandas.plotting import autocorrelation_plot
autocorrelation_plot(df)
```

I have this error message :

```
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, float found
```

What is the problem ? Help please ? Thx !

Comment: You cannot pass an entire DataFrame to that function. You need to pass a single Series (you probably want the last one: `autocorrelation_plot(df['sum_event_count'])`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need pass `Series` as commented [ayhan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49978909/calculating-autocorrelation-acf-coercing-to-unicode-need-string-or-buffer/49979094#comment86973856_49978909).

[Autocorrelation in docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#visualization-autocorrelation):

> Autocorrelation plots are often used for checking randomness in time series. This is done by computing autocorrelations for data values at varying time lags. If time series is random, such autocorrelations should be near zero for any and all time-lag separations. If time series is non-random then one or more of the autocorrelations will be significantly non-zero. The horizontal lines displayed in the plot correspond to 95% and 99% confidence bands. The dashed line is 99% confidence band.

```
from pandas.plotting import autocorrelation_plot
autocorrelation_plot(df['sum_event_count'])
```

If need `time series` add [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
from pandas.plotting import autocorrelation_plot
autocorrelation_plot(df.set_index('DATE')['sum_event_count'])
```